# How do I find the minimum using which.min function within the function I built?

Tags: r, sample

I would like to build that function that allows me to import any dataset (i.e. Dataset1) which I will use as my chosen number and sample numbers to find the difference (Difference = (chosen number - sample number) ^ 2) and then find the average. With that, I would then like to find which chosen number from Dataset1 will give me the minimum average (this will be the output for my function). Note that for my chosen numbers, it could be from Dataset1 or numbers outside of Dataset1, including real numbers.

```
Dataset1 <- c(12739, 172392, 16477, 14738, 12223, 15473, 18999, 12278)

simulation.model <- function(import.dataset){ 
  test.df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 1000))
  colnames(test.df) <- c("Dataset","R_Sample","Payment","Mean_Payment" )
  sample.numbers <- sample(c(import.dataset, size = 1000, replace = FALSE))
  
  f <- 0
  for (i in dataset)
    test.df[i,2] <- sample(c(dataset, size = 1000, replace = FALSE))
    test.df[i,3] <-(dataset[i] - sample.numbers)^2
  
    test.df[i,4] <- mean(insert.dataset[i]$Payment)
    choice <- test.df[which.min(test.df$MeanPayment)]$Dataset
  
  return(c(chosen = choice))
}

new.simulation.function(Dataset1)
```

I am getting an error for my function - any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `for (i in dataset)`  I don't see `dataset` initialized to anything so there is no index.

Comment: BTW, you also have to wrap your `for` content with braces.  And re: `return(c(chosen = choice))`  If you want to return that, it has to happen outside the loop.  The standard practice is to increment a pre-initialized vector or list inside the loop and then return that object outside the loop.

Comment: Lots of name inconsistency. The argument is `import.dataset`. The loop set-up uses `dataset`. The average uses `insert.dataset`. A separate issue: your test data `Dataset1` has 8 values, but you try to sample 1000 items from the input **without replacement**--meaning your function will error if the input has less than 1000 items. You either need a much larger test input or a change your function to accept smaller inputs (maybe `replace = TRUE`?).

Comment: ...and `test.df` is a data frame, so `test.df[which.min(test.df$MeanPayment)]$Dataset` dimensionally won't work, try `test.df[which.min(test.df$MeanPayment), "Dataset"]`.

Comment: There are so many problems here, I'd strongly recommend opening a new R session and trying to get a small example to work **not** in a function (say 10 instead of 1000 samples). Then, when you've got some code you can run top to bottom without errors, only then should you try to put it in a function.